# Moving from tokend to in Cryptotoken kit code signing

Tags: macos, code-signing, macos-catalina, tokend, cryptotokenkit

We have a code signing setup using HSM over network. On mac we were using tokend previously but with macOS 10.15 tokend is disabled and we need to move to Cryptotokenkit. Is there any possible suggestion/solution available in which we can fetch the token from network based HSM instead of smartcard?

Comment: What HSM are you using?

Answer (score 0):

We had to deal with this and it was a pain. I was tasked to take a look at what would be involved in migrating from tokend to CTK and it looked like a very tough task. We eventually got it working with third party software. There were a couple products we looked at but we ended up selecting [GaraSign](https://garantir.io/use-cases/code-signing/). At the time they were the only one who had macOS signing working but I believe some of their competitors now have it too.